# Hypothesis testing (confused, I need some help)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, inference

An urn contains 10 marbles with $M$ white and $10-M$ black. To test that $M=5$ against the alternative hypothesis that $M=6$, one draws $3$ marbles from the urn without replacement. The null hypothesis is rejected if the sample contains $2$ or $3$ white marbles; otherwise it is accepted. What is the size of this test and power?

Comment: Please read the `[self-study]` tag's 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left of the Answer if you don't have any follow-up questions. And I almost forgot... Welcome to this site! Hope to see you back!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

Since I had the impending feeling of doing homework on the initial answer, and in full disclosure I was never asked to do so, I want now to add something less homework-*y*. Simply some code in [R] to prove that the analytical results in the body of the reply using the hypergeometric distribution can be reproduced with a Monte Carlo simulation:

i. Type I Error Rate Calculation:

```
B <- c(rep(0, 5)) # We will "build up" the urn with five black balls with a "0" on them.
W <- c(rep(1, 5)) #... and 5 white balls with a "1" coded on them. 
(urn <- c(W, B)) #... and we get this "NULL" hypothesis URN.
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
samples <- replicate(1e6, sample(urn, 3)) # Let's take 1 million samples from this urn.
Num_Whites <- colSums(samples) # And count the number of white balls in each sample.
(p_value <- length(Num_Whites[Num_Whites>=2])/length(Num_Whites)) # % > or = 2 Whites.
p value = 0.499898
```

ii. Power of the Test:

```
B <- c(rep(0, 4)) # Now we are under the alternative hypothesis - only 4 Black balls
W <- c(rep(1, 6)) #... and 6 White...
urn <- c(W, B) # ... in our new URN.
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
samples <- replicate(1e6, sample(urn, 3)) # Otherwise, same process.
Num_Whites <- colSums(samples)
(power <- 1 - (length(Num_Whites[Num_Whites==1])/length(Num_Whites))) # 1 - beta
Power = 0.699862
```

---

Given our cut-off limit of 2 or 3 white balls, we are going to be contemplating the probabilities of these two tables:

For $\Tiny W=2$:

```
Color       Drawn     Remaining      Margin
  White     2         M - 2          M     
  Black     1         9 - M          10 - M  
  Margin    3         7              10
```

and for $\Tiny W=3$:

```
Color       Drawn     Remaining      Margin
  White     3         M - 3          M     
  Black     0         10 - M         10 - M  
  Margin    3         7              10
```

The margins are fixed as in these type of [tea-and-milk hypergeometric experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_tasting_tea).

The first question is the *size of the test* or probability of a type I error. So we find ourselves *under* $\small H_o=5\,whites$, and we are interested in calculating the probability of getting these tables, *knowing (= under the null)* that $\small M=5$:

For $\Tiny W=2$:

```
Color    Drawn Remaining Margin
  White      2         3      5
  Black      1         4      5
  Margin     3         7     10
```

$p\,(W=2)=\frac{{5\choose2}\,{5\choose1}}{10\choose3}\,=\,0.4166$

while for $\Tiny W=3$:

```
Color    Drawn Remaining Margin
  White      3         2      5
  Black      0         5      5
  Margin     3         7     10
```

$p\,(W=3)=\frac{{5\choose3}\,{5\choose0}}{10\choose3}\,=\,0.0833$

Adding them up, then: $p\,(type\, I \,error)= 0.5$!

And for the power, first we have to calculate $beta$ or the probability of accepting the null hypothesis *under* the alternative. So we assume now that we know that $\small M= 6$. We are going to incorrectly accept the null (given our self-imposed cut-off at two white balls) when we get only one white ball. This will happen with a probability of:

$p\,(W=1)=\frac{{6\choose1}\,{4\choose2}}{10\choose3}\,=\,0.3$.

Hence, the actual *power* to reject the null when the alternative is true is going to be $power=1-\beta=1-0.3=0.7$.

Assuming I didn't do a goofy mistake, the actual results are what they are, but I believe the true story of this post is that there is no free lunch: when we accept a cut-off limit in the test statistic that is too low (in this case concluding that there more white than black balls simply from observing 2 whites out of a draw of 3), we get a great propensity of drawing a false $H_1$ conclusion. At the same time, we do see the inverse relationship with the power of the test.